# asp.net mvc - racing condition : lock a method with same parameters

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-3, thread-safety

I am developing an asp.net mvc 3 web application.
In my application I've got a javascript client sending calls to my server.
One of the calls is directed to a method of mine, that in turn:

- Creates a new instance of an object -
- Saves it to the database
- Calls a remote web server.

I decide if to exit the function by querying my database to see if the object truly does exist (if so, I exit).

My problem is that if two calls are made just one after the other, the object hasn't had the chance to be saved to the database, and so both threads will think that they need to continue.

What I'd like is to lock the method for only threads that are called with the same parameters. Using a lock on the entire method, or even parts of it is unacceptable, as it will cause severe performance issues.

How can this be done?

Comment: Check it at the database level. When one of them saves, the other will fail because it would violate some sort of constraint.

Comment: you could create a hashtable and first check to see if the object already exists ... if it doesn't then continue creating it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use database transactions with serializable isolation level for this scenario. This should ensure the consistency of your read and insert operations.